# Why HashedSet forces loading lazy collection?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I query items with lazy collections in via nHibernate. Items are queried without fetching collections. But when i try to create HashedSet

```
var hashedSet = new HashedSet<Thing>(Session.Query<Thing>())
```

from those items all lazy stuff is fetched. Whats causing that?

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Thing {
        public virtual String Name { get; set; }       
        public Thing() {
            OtherThings = new HashedSet<OtherThing>();              
        }

        public virtual ISet<OtherThing> OtherThings { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: can you show us the code where you get `Items` from and ityemtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have overridden `GetHashCode()` in the entity (or any base class of it) and access the properties there?